# Method of Lagrange multipliers to find all critical points of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am having difficulties in understanding the steps/method required to find the critical points of a function using the method of Lagrange multipliers. I have read through my text book and tried my best to understand the steps but they seem a bit too advanced.

Here is an example of the type of question I am working on:

> Consider the constrained optimization problem:
>   $$
> \text{Optimise } \,f(x,y,z) \text{ subject to the constraint: } x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4.
> $$
>   Use the method of Lagrange multipliers to find all the critical points of this constrained optimization problem.

If anyone could show me the steps in a simple, comprehensive way I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us discuss the example you were given.  Generally, this optimization method uses the following strategy.  Let $f(x,y,z)$ be the function that we are attempting to determine the critical points for, subject to the constraint equation $$g(x,y,z)=k$$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$.  We solve the following system:
$$\nabla f(x,y,z) = \lambda \nabla g(x,y,z) \\g(x,y,z)=k$$
of four equations and four unknowns (note that $\nabla$ is the gradient function which returns the vector composed of partial derivatives with respect to $x$, $y$, and $z$).
In this case, we have $f(x,y,z)=2x+y-2z$ and $g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ (this is a sphere of radius $2$).  Thus, we have the following system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}2 = 2\lambda x \,\,\,\,\,\,(f_x = \lambda g_x) \\ 1 = 2\lambda y \,\,\,\,\,\, (f_y=\lambda g_y)\\ -2 = 2\lambda z \,\,\,\,\,(f_z= \lambda g_z)\\ x^2+y^2+z^2=4\end{cases}$$
There are various ways that you can solve this, but we will solve in the following way.  Multiplying the first equation by $yz$, the second equation by $xz$, and the third equation by $xy$ and setting each of these equal to one another, we obtain $$2\lambda xyz = \begin{cases} 2yz \\ xz \\ -2xy \end{cases}$$
So, first we have $x = 2y$ upon dividing $2yz=xz$ by $z \neq 0$. Then we also have $z=-2y$ upon dividing $xz=-2xy$ by $x \neq 0$. Finally, we have $x=-z$ upon dividing $2yz = -2xy$ by $2y \neq 0$. Applying this, we substitute for $x$ and $z$ in terms of $y$ into the fourth equation to get
$$x^2 +y^2 +z^2 =4 \implies 4y^2 + y^2 + 4y^2 = 9y^2 = 4 \implies y = \mp \frac{2}{3}$$
I will let you solve for the other $3$ unknowns (consider each case separately: assume $y = -\frac{2}{3}$ and solve for $x,z,\lambda$ and then assume $y=\frac{2}{3}$ and solve for $x,z,\lambda$). Recall from before that $z = -2y$ and $x=-z$.  You will find the two solutions
$$(x,y,z,\lambda)=\left(\mp \frac{4}{3},\mp \frac{2}{3}, \pm \frac{4}{3},\mp \frac{3}{4}\right) .$$
These solutions $(x,y,z)$ are the critical points of the function $f$ under this constraint $g(x,y,z)=4$ and we can use multiple ways to classify them (as, for instance, maximums, minimums, or saddle points).

Comment: Thank you for your reply @afedder. I have a fair understanding of your working but I am a little bit confused as to how you got from the set of equations to the solutions (critical points)?

Comment: I'll edit to include an example of solving the equations. @user136954

Comment: Thank you for that @afedder.

Comment: Please see my edit @user136954...if it is helpful, I would appreciate an accept/upvote.

Comment: *Would you be able to explain to me where you got the value 9 from? I'm a little stuck on that equation! @afedder

Comment: Ok so we have $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ as your constraint equation. We are substituting $x$ as a function of $y$, which is $x= 2y$, and $z$ as a function of $y$, which is $z = -2y$...

Comment: ...Thus, we obtain $$ \begin{align} x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4 &\iff (2y)^2 + y^2 + (-2y)^2 = 4 \\ &\iff 4y^2 + y^2 + 4y^2 = 4 \\ &\iff \text{(summing the terms on the LHS)} \,\,\,\, 9y^2 = 4 \\ &\iff y = \mp \frac{2}{3} \,.\end{align}$$

Comment: Alright, I think I am beginning to understand the concepts. One last question, would you be able to show me how you'd write out the second equation out of the four? I don't quite see what I have to do differently @afedder.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "second equation". However to obtain $f_y = \lambda g_y$, which is the second equation of the system of four, you take the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$ to get $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y,z) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(2x+y-2z) = 1\,\,,$$ and then you take the partial derivative of $g$ with respect to $y$ to get $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x,y,z) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) = 2y\,\,.$$ Finally, set the former equal to a constant multiple $\lambda$ of the latter to get the equation $$1 = 2\lambda y \,\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

let $f(x,y,z,\lambda)=2x+y-2z+\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-4)$

Then $f_x=2+2\lambda x=0\implies x=\dfrac{-1}{\lambda}$

$f_y=1+2\lambda y=0\implies y=\dfrac{-1}{2\lambda}$

$f_z=-2+2\lambda z=0 \implies z=\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$

$f_\lambda=x^2+y^2+z^2-4=0 \implies x^2+y^2+z^2=4$

Now substituting value of $x$, $y$ and $z$ in the above equation we get $$\dfrac{2}{{\lambda}^2}+\dfrac{1}{4{\lambda}^2}=4$$

Now solving for $\lambda$, we get $9=16\lambda^2$, giving $\lambda=\dfrac{3}{4}$ or $\lambda=-\dfrac{3}{4}$.

For $\lambda=\dfrac{3}{4}$, $(x,y,z)=\left(\dfrac{-4}{3},\dfrac{-4}{6},\dfrac{4}{3}\right)$ and for $\lambda=\dfrac{-3}{4}$, $(x,y,z)=\left(\dfrac{4}{3},\dfrac{4}{6},\dfrac{-4}{3}\right)$.

These are the two critical points